# Video Editing - Send a strip to another scene same project file

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene, outliner

[image: Send strip to another scene.]

I am trying to do some video editing and I want to send a metastrip or strip from one scene to another scene. But copy and paste doesn't work because it do not copy the curve animations, just the strips and all the fade in and out are gone. Is there another way to send a video strip from one scene to another scene?

Attached image: from the scene in red "logo" to the scene in blue "Scene_01".

Answer (score 1):

I already found it! Well, I'll leave it here if someone else has the same issue:

In SEQUENCER just click on ADD> SCENE> Choose your scene. In the right panel on the "STRIP" tab go to SCENE and change the INPUT to SEQUENCER insted of camera. Done.